# Browser unwanted behaviour using OAuth protocol

Tags: android, android-activity

So I have a software that uses OAuth protocol for doing authorization operations. In the main menu I have a button that starts an activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, HattrickOAuth.class);
this.startActivityForResult(i,OAUTH_ID);
```

In the `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method of **HattrickOAuth** class we need to start the browser to redirect the user to the authorization page. I use:

```
Intent browser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(authUrl));                    browser.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
browser.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
this.startActivity(browser);
```

In the onResume() I have the completion of the authorization and I return the result calling

```
setResult(RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

The problem is that this is going back to the browser and not on the menu. Is there something I'm missing? To go back I use the following **scheme** in the manifest:

```
<activity
    android:label="@string/oauth_name"
    android:name=".hattrick.HattrickOAuth"
    android:theme="@style/MainStyle" >
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="hattrick"
            android:scheme="h4m-app" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Hi dierre Did you manage to get any solution for the issue

Comment: not really. We used a workaround. I'll ask my colleague to post it.